# A sequence of functor comes from derived functor

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Suppose we have two abelian categories $A$ and $B$.
Assume that $A$ has enough injectives.
Now consider a sequence of functors $F_0,F_1,F_2,....$.

Such that a short exact sequence in $A$ induces a long exact sequence in terms of $F_i$. Can we then claim that $F_i$ are the right derived functors of the functor $F_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume the long exact sequence obtained is functorial in the short exact sequence, then the collection of functors $F_i$ you describe are called a [Delta-functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-functor). Delta functors do not always arise as derived functors. A somewhat trivial counterexample: fix a left exact functor $F$, let $F_0=0$ and $F_n=R^{n-1}F$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! What if the the value of $F_i()$ is zero on injectives? Then is the statement true?

Comment: @grok If $F^n$ are zero on injectives for $n > 0$, then in particular $F^n$ form an effaceable $\delta$-functor, and a theorem of Grothendieck from Tôhoku says that an effaceable $\delta$-functor is universal. Then, right derived functors of a left exact $F$ are by definition a universal $\delta$-functor $R^n F$ such that $R^0 F \cong F$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it!

Comment: And it's Exercise 2.4.5 in Weibel :-)